# TimePicker hour doesn't update after switching to 24h

Tags: android, time, timepicker

For example when I create this timePicker(below) at 18:00, the timePicker's timeValue will be 06:00. At 19:44->07:44... So it doesn't move to the correct current hour after switching from AM/PM to 24h mode. How can I change that?
My goal is that the timePicker shows the current time when it was created. Like it does when I use it in AM/PM mode.

```
TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);
timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
```

Sry for the bad formulation, hope you can understand my question. Otherwise just ask.

UPDATE:

```
public class ChooseTimeViewDialog extends AlertDialog {

    protected Context context;


    public ChooseTimeViewDialog(final Context context) {
        super(context);     
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

        View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_choose_time_view, null);
        setContentView(convertView);
        setTitle(R.string.title_dialog_choose_time_view);

        final TimePicker taskTimePicker = (TimePicker) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dctv_task_time_picker);
        taskTimePicker.setIs24HourView(true);


        setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Choose", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                int hour = taskTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
                int minute = taskTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();

                Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                cal.set(0, 0, 0, hour, minute, 0);

                ((AddTaskViewActivity) context).setSelectedTime(cal.getTime());
            }
        });
        setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "No time", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ((AddTaskViewActivity) context).setSelectedTime(null);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/dctv_task_time_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

After I moved the initialiation to onCreate and used the setContentView(View), the background of the dialog is transparent, it's fullscreen and has no buttons..why?

Comment: Well I could fix it, but it's not really a nice solution, any better?

timePicker.setCurrentHour(new Date().getHours());

Comment: When is this code executed? Many widgets won't redraw magically after they are created.

Comment: It's executed in the constructor of a custom AlertDialog called ChooseTimeDialog that I made. Every time I open the dialog I create a new object of it: new ChooseTimeDialog(this).show();

Comment: @rds Your comment sounds a little sarcastic and confused, unless you believe methods like `setCurrentHour()` are "magic".

Comment: Why don't you call `setCurrentHour()` after calling `setIs24HourView()`?

Comment: @Sam like I said, I can use  timePicker.setCurrentHour(new Date().getHours()), but that's not the solution I want. It should be possible to solve it in a better way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I can use timePicker.setCurrentHour(new Date().getHours()), but that's not the solution I want. It should be possible to solve it in a better way.

Looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/TimePicker.java#TimePicker.setIs24HourView%28java.lang.Boolean%29), this is a bug that appeared sometime after API 10:

```
public void setIs24HourView(Boolean is24HourView) {
    if (mIs24HourView == is24HourView) {
        return;
    }
    mIs24HourView = is24HourView; 
    // cache the current hour since spinner range changes
    int currentHour = getCurrentHour();
    updateHourControl();
    // set value after spinner range is updated
    setCurrentHour(currentHour);
    updateAmPmControl();
}
```

The correct order is:

```
// cache the current hour since spinner range changes
int currentHour = getCurrentHour();
mIs24HourView = is24HourView;
```

Because `getCurrentHour()` relies on `mIs24HourView` to return 1-12 or 0-23...

But until the source code is updated and deployed, you don't have much of a choice. You need to call `setCurrentHour()` after `setIs24HourView()` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you should initialize your dialog in [`onCreate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Comment: When I initialize it in onCreate and also use setContentView(view), the dialog has transparent background, fills the whole screen and has no buttons.... I'll post the whole code in my question, maybe someone finds the mistake

Comment: I'm sorry, but do you may know why it's not working fine when I use onCreate instead of the constructor? Its driving me crazy! Seems as all the setButton(), setTitle() mehtods are ignored...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, if you are using Xamarin then you can do the same thing by subclassing the TimePicker and overriding SetIs24HourView like so:

```
public class TwentyFourHourMvxTimePicker : MvxTimePicker
{
    public TwentyFourHourMvxTimePicker(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base (context, attrs)
    {

    }

    public override void SetIs24HourView (Java.Lang.Boolean is24HourView)
    {
        var current = CurrentHour;
        base.SetIs24HourView(is24HourView); 
        CurrentHour = current;
    }
}
```