# Android: TimePicker setIs24HourView not working

Tags: android, timepicker

I am trying to use the TimePicker in the 24 hour format and I am using setIs24HourView= true, but I am still not getting 24 hour format on the TimePicker. Here is my code in the onCreate of the Activity.

```
    timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
```

I even tried timePicker.setCurrentHour(cal.HOUR_OF_DAY) after setIs24HourView, but I am not able to see the 24 hour format on the TimePicker.

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp" />
```

Am I missing anything here?

[image]

Comment: are you not seeing it change in Eclipse, or when you run it?

Comment: I guess there is issue with findViewById. Make sure it is inside main activity or if is inside inflated view then you need to use like infaltedView.findViewById

Comment: I am not seeing the changes when I run it. This is inside oncreate of the main activity.

Comment: hmm... are you setting the time at all in code? this all works no problem when i run it

Comment: Maybe post a screenshot of what you're actually seeing so we can better understand the problem. I'm not sure why the above isn't working for you

Comment: No, when I don't set any time and just do setIs24HourView(true) , it shows the correct time (in the 12 hour format). When i just tried timePicker.setCurrentHour(cal.HOUR_OF_DAY), it  shows wrong time in 12 hour format.

Comment: your screen shot looks like it is in 24h mode to me, there isn't any am/pm selector...

Comment: Sammys is right.. when HOUR_OF_DAY is 0 than it automatically display 12 in TimePicker..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ok, I see what the problem is now. 
It's not correctly setting the currentHour to the new 24 hour format, which is why you got 9:05 instead of 21:05. I'm guessing it isn't 9am where you are!
It is a bug, as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662288/timepicker-hour-doesnt-update-after-switching-to-24h)
seems the only work around, for now, is to do something like:

```
timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
timePicker.setCurrentHour(Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

I see you tried cal.HOUR_OF_DAY, but didn't provide the code you actually used, but try this and see if it helps.

Comment: thank you! setting timePicker.setCurrentHour(Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) worked!

Comment: But `get` is not a static method ... how this could work? You must instantiate Calendar with `getInstance` and then call `get`.

Comment: That code is not Working than HOUR_OF_DAY is 0 because that Time Picker is display automatically 12..

Comment: @enrmarc is right, you must do it like this:
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
timePicker.setCurrentHour(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

Answer (score 8):

I notice this problem in jelly bean You can set the time to show in 24 hour view

```
    TimePicker picker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    picker.setIs24HourView(true);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int h = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int m = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    picker.setCurrentHour(h);
    picker.setCurrentMinute(m);
```

Comment: here this code set HOUR_OF_DAY is o to 11 and leave screen and come back than hour is automatically change check it.. you set 0 than display 12 after enter screen again..

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the device settings and thus let the user make this decision;

```
 String clockType = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.TIME_12_24);
```

Answer (score 0):

setting `timePicker.setCurrentHour(Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))` solved the problem

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. Accepted your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

```
timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
```

We need to add this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

timePicker.setCurrentHour(calendar.get(calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```