# Incorrect time showing in timePicker

Tags: android, timepicker

I have a Time picker in my app the is set to 24h format. This is the code in my class:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();        
//Bundle args = getArguments();
SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int hourOfTheDay = preferences.getInt("TEST_TIME_OF_DAY_HOUR", 10);
int minuteOfTheDay = preferences.getInt("TEST_TIME_OF_DAY_HOUR", 0);

// TODO: bug in time picker --> needs hour to be set again after is24HourFormat
// see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150430/android-timepicker-setis24hourview-not-working
// tried solution but method not available

 TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hourOfTheDay, minuteOfTheDay,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));


return timePickerDialog;
}
```

As you can see, I am indicating time format 24h and I am passing in 10 as the hour. However the picker shows up indicating 22:00 and not 10:00. I found some information here saying it could be a bug [Android: TimePicker setIs24HourView not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150430/android-timepicker-setis24hourview-not-working), but the class I am using is TimePickerDialog and does not have the a method that allows me to set the time separately as suggested in the solution (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html).

It is now afternoon where I am (evening actually). The emulator I am using has the time set to 24h. Before, I had it set to AM/PM and the same code above was bringing up the time picker as 10am...

What I am looking to implement is: time picker has 24h format and is initiated with 10:00 (as in morning time).

I'm not sure this is a bug or something I am doing wrong.

Comment: from the code of TimePickerDialog, there is no reason why 10 should be transformed into 22. are you absolutely positive hourOfTheDay == 10? Since this comes from a preference, is is possible that it was modified when you were displaying am/pm dialog?

Comment: Actually I haven't yet implemented those preferences anywhere in the app, hence the default always shows. For instance, I tried modifying the default to 11 and the time picker shows 11. Now the strange thing is that the bug is gone since I had to reinstall the app to test 11. Note that preferences are kept when reinstalling the app unless you purposefully clear the data on the phone, which I didn't do. I'm not exactly sure what happened. Anyway it's gone.

Comment: ok. strange indeed. marking for closing as `can no longer be reproduced`