# Q: Android TimePicker.setIs24HourView does not work

Tags: android, timepicker

I wrote PreferenceDialog with TimePicker. But when i set this control to 24 hour mode i got exception Error inflating class.

```
public class TimePreference extends DialogPreference {
    
        private int hour = 0;
        private int minute = 0;
    
        private TimePicker timePicker;
    
    
      
        public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(ctxt, attrs);
            setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.timedialog_preference);
            timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
            setPositiveButtonText("Ok");
            setNegativeButtonText("Cancel");
        }
    }
```

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: You can see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150430/android-timepicker-setis24hourview-not-working

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem. Code:

public class TimeDialogPrefFragCompat extends PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat {

```
private TimePicker timePicker;

@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
    super.onBindDialogView(view);


    timePicker  = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);
    timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int h = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int m = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    timePicker.setCurrentHour(h);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(m);
    }
}
```

}

need to be write in onBindDialogView method.